# Table border radius - global css (thead OR tbody selector)

Tags: html, css, frontend

I rewrite some css for a big site. There's lot of content and the content often differs.

I'm somehow stuck on css tables.

My new tables should have rounded borders. Thankfully, I can use CSS only (it can graceful degrade down to IE7), so I will use CSS only.

Tables onsite differs. Some has table header, some doesn't.

As we all know, border-radius doesn't work on table itself. It has to be a table cell argument.

Is there any possibility to write the CSS, so a browser would recognize if the table has thead (and then set border-radius for "table thead tr:first-child th:first-child"), and if not border-radius would be set for "table tbody tr:first-child td:first-child")?

Quick simple shot I tried doesn't work - "table tr:first-child td:first-child"  - as I should assume if I would think about it - it sets border-radius for both "thead th" and "tbody td".

If you have any possible solution I'd be grateful. CSS3 only solutions are fine enough for me.

Comment: what do you mean by "As we all know, border-radius doesn't work on table itself"? [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/fhBuS/)

Comment: in addition you shouldn't use `border-radius` on table inner elements. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius - see `5.6. Effect on Tables`

Comment: @Peter: well, I didn't mention, that all tables onsite are border collapsed. Sorry for misleading.

Comment: [what about this](http://jsfiddle.net/fhBuS/3/)?

Comment: btw. you can use `border-spacing` instead of `border-collapse` example: http://jsfiddle.net/fhBuS/4/

Comment: @Peter I don't think so. As I said, there are numbers of different tables. Border should collapse.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to count the th tags and set a class on the table if it found any...

```
var thCount = $("#theTable tr th").length;

   if (thCount > 0){
     $("#theTable").addClass("roundCorners"); 
     //adds a class to the table so you can make round corners
   }
```

This example assumes you already have some form of ID/Class on the table, just need to change as necessary and use your CSS.